# Invoke-Command behavior clarification

Tags: powershell, windows-authentication, kerberos, powershell-4.0, invoke-command

I'm running into some trouble with the Invoke-Command cmdlet. I am logged into my local machine with my domain identity, which has admin rights on `$server`. If I manually enter my credentials, then use Invoke-Command, I get the error:

> Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer ''. This operation might require other privileges.

```
# Works
Get-Service -ComputerName $server-ErrorAction Ignore

# Doesn't work
$cred = Get-Credential
Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -ScriptBlock {param($serverIPAddress) Get-Service -ComputerName $server -ErrorAction Ignore} -Credential $cred -ArgumentList $server
```

Is there something special about the built-in credentials that makes this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the classic kerberos double-hop.

The special thing that's happening is that the local computer has your credentials. It can talk to a remote computer and prove it has the credentials, without ever sending them.

However if the remote computer needs to access something on a third computer (second hop), it cannot prove it has the credentials (because it doesn't), so it cannot authenticate.

This is Kerberos working as designed.

Using `Invoke-Command` to localhost is still doing a remoting connection, so it still counts as a hop. The `Get-Service` call is a second hop.

---

Consider:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock { Get-Service -ErrorAction Ignore } -Credential $cred
```

That will work (as long as powershell remoting is enabled on the remote machine).

Otherwise, you need to enable kerberos delegation, or CredSSP, or (best if possible) rework whatever you're doing to not require a double hop.

[Be wary of CredSSP (and delegation in general).](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/03/06/accidental-sabotage-beware-of-credssp/)

Comment: I was hoping to avoid turning on powershell remoting, as I have never used it before and don't know if I can sell it to the IT team. Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: @Vlad274 consider that in windows server 2012 and higher, powershell remoting is enabled out of the box. I find that to be a strong argument in favor of enabling it that seems to resonate with other IT pros who are hesitant.